# Cannot run Hakyll on macOS Sierra: malformed mach-o: load commands size

Tags: haskell, macos-sierra, cabal, hakyll, cabal-sandbox

I can compile Hakyll, but when I try to run it I get a linking error.
First I install Hakyll in a sandbox:

```
cabal sandbox init
cabal install Hakyll
```

This completes successfully.
Then I create a plain site using `hakyll-init` and move the files up a directory:

```
.cabal-sandbox/bin/hakyll-init mysite
mv mysite/* .
rm -rf mysite
```

Then I try to run it with `cabal exec -- runghc site.hs build` and I get:

```
site.hs: <command line>: can't load .so/.DLL for: /Users/john/repositories/CP/principles-of-concurrent-programming/Website/.cabal-sandbox/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.2.1/libHSpandoc-citeproc-0.10.5.1-97wWmtk04v65Etcjop52Rs-ghc8.2.1.dylib (dlopen(/Users/john/repositories/CP/principles-of-concurrent-programming/Website/.cabal-sandbox/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.2.1/libHSpandoc-citeproc-0.10.5.1-97wWmtk04v65Etcjop52Rs-ghc8.2.1.dylib, 5): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/john/repositories/CP/principles-of-concurrent-programming/Website/.cabal-sandbox/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.2.1/libHSpandoc-citeproc-0.10.5.1-97wWmtk04v65Etcjop52Rs-ghc8.2.1.dylib: malformed mach-o: load commands size (32992) > 32768
    /Users/john/repositories/CP/principles-of-concurrent-programming/Website/.cabal-sandbox/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-8.2.1/libHSpandoc-citeproc-0.10.5.1-97wWmtk04v65Etcjop52Rs-ghc8.2.1.dylib: malformed mach-o: load commands size (32992) > 32768)
```

- The contents of `site.hs` are completely standard. I've uploaded the file to [gist](https://gist.github.com/johnjcamilleri/1c363c6f6cdea98ab278d680c46bf272).
- **GHC 8.2.1**, installed via Homebrew. I initially had this problem with 7.10.3b, and upgraded GHC to see if that would help. It didn't.
- **macOS Sierra 10.12.6**

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try installing via stack and see if that works.

Comment: You can also use Nix to install it. The hakyll build for darwin succeeds in the latest version of nixpkgs. Sadly, I can't test it because I don't have an OS X machine at my disposal. You can get Nix at https://nixos.org/nix/ and try: `nix-build -iA haskellPackages.hakyll -I nixpkgs=https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/6bbc3a0b245ccf392a8ddbce41b372c17409f0e9.tar.gz`

Comment: can you show your website.hs?

Comment: @mlambrichs I've updated the question to specify that this happens with a completely fresh site generated using `hakyll-init`.

Comment: @Sibi just tried with stack and indeed it works great. I guess I will post this as an answer

Answer (score 2):

Although not exactly a solution to my problem, I managed to get around this by installing Hakyll through stack instead. For the record, these were my steps:

```sh
brew install haskell-stack
stack setup
stack install hakyll
```

Then to build the website:

```sh
stack exec -- runghc site.hs build
```